# How does Backgrid know what numbers to generate for pagination?

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

I'm implementing pagination for my Backgrid powered tables, like so:

```
footer: Backgrid.Extension.Paginator
```

And in my Collection:

```
state: {
   pageSize: 15
}
```

Now, I haven't actually implemented any handling of pagination server side (which is what I feel might be producing odd results), but it put this HTML in:

[image]

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sort of a bug and sort of a mismatched expectation.

The reason it started paging backwards is because your server mode `Backbone.PageableCollection` didn't have a `totalRecords` set in `state`, which is required under server mode according to the [documentation.](https://github.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable#introduction)

In addition, `Backgrid.Extension.Paginator` has a default sliding window of 10 pages, but apparently version 0.1 made an assumption that the collection won't be empty when you decide to summon up a grid, (it basically assumed you'd follow the [recommended best practice here](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap)), so this case was never checked. Following the progress of this [issue here.](https://github.com/wyuenho/backgrid/issues/33)